# IBOutletCollection in Xcode 5.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, iboutletcollection

I want to create an `IBOutletCollection` for a list of controls in my application. So in my `Document.h` I have defined the following outlet:

```
@property (strong) IBOutletCollection(NSControl) NSArray *myControls;
```

In earlier versions the **Outlet Collections** did show up in the respective Inspector in Xcode, but this does not seem to be the case in Xcode 5.1

#### Outlet Collections before

[image]

#### In my case no Outlet Collections visible in the inspector:

[image]

How can I re-enable this behaviour?

Comment: I am not having this issue, it is visible for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you tagged the questions with the OS X tag, I am assuming you are developing a Mac project.
`IBOutletCollections` are not supported by AppKit.

UIKit has `UINibDeclarations.h` which defines:

```
#ifndef IBOutletCollection
#define IBOutletCollection(ClassName)
#endif
```

The AppKit counterpart `NSNibDeclarations.h` has no such define.